# CartoDB storage and Mapviews

Tags: carto

I had setup cartoDB locally in my server. I am very curious to know about the free storage space alloted (in means of mapviews, tables, Data Storage) for using cartoDB from my own server for private views. And also, below is a snapshot of cartoDB storage statistics after setting in my own server. In that it is mentioned 10GB of space and 10k mapviews are free to use. I would like to know 10kmapviews for per month or year? I would also like to know is there any possiblity of storing the data in external sources like my own server and use cartoDB API alone for customization and In this case, will this charge?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your custom CartoDB installation, any of the limits of the CartoDB.com service apply.

In your screenshot I'm seeing that you are using a really old CartoDB version. Right now the CartoDB.com service does not charge anymore per map views, neither has a limit in the amount of created tables. In terms of storage quota, this is not a "monthly" limit, it's just a general limit. In your account, you can store up to X MB of data.

If you are working in your own server, you can edit your own accounts settings in order to give yourself more quota or any other features.

Comment: Is there any possibility to upgrade to a new cartoDB version. If so, is there any documentation for the same?

Comment: You would need to do a pull in the github repo, but take into account that new versions might require database migrations that you would need to manage. Everything is available here: https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/